# Relocating an app.config config section to the AppData folder

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, configuration, app-config

I have a **Windows Forms** application that connects to a web service that is configured in the app.config under the typical `configuration\system.serviceModel\client\endpoint` node like so:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      ...
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://blahblah/service.asmx" ... />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This application is often used on fairly locked down Windows systems, such that administrator rights are required (typically via UAC) to modify any files within the Program Files directory in which the application is installed. That is fine for most configuration, as it should not be user configurable.

I would like to relocate the endpoint configuration to the user's app data folder, so that this can be modified at a later date, post installation, and without any administrator intervention.

I understand I can use the `configSource` attribute of the client element under system.serviceModel to point to a separate config file however this does not seem to support absolute paths (let alone ideally also the appdata environment variable), and hence does not appear to be an option for pointing to appdata.

My question therefore is, how can I relocate this configuration block to an external file in the user's appdata folder where it can be modified without subsequent administrator intervention whilst leaving the rest of the configuration securely in the program files installation folder?

Answer (score 1):

You need "externalize" your `<client>` section like this:

- Move the contents of your `<client>` section to a new file, e.g. `~/App_Data/Config/Client.config":

  ```
  <client>
      <endpoint address="http://blahblah/service.asmx" ... />
  </client>
  ```
- Modify our existing config to point to that externalized config file:

  ```
  <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
      ...
      </bindings>
      <client configSource="/App_Data/Config/Client.config" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  ```

Now, you can modify our client settings in that external file, without having to touch the main `web.config` file anymore.

Just word of caution: while changing the `web.config` also automatically causes the IIS application pool to recycle (and thus reload the new config), this is **no longer** the case when you modify such an externalized config file. So you'll need to explicitly recycle the IIS app pool to get the new settings reloaded from your config file

Comment: Hi Marc, apologies, I think my original post may have misled you, as I say this is a Windows Forms application, and not a web application, so I'm referring to the Application Data folder typically under C:\Users\username\AppData rather than the App_Data in a web application and this isn't a sub-directory of the application folder so I do not believe configSource works. I've retagged appdata to winforms to make this more clear, and highlighted Windows Forms in my post in bold. Apologies.

Comment: @Xefan: you can still use the "config externalization" feature, but I believe this is *limited* to the directory where the application is installed (and any subfolders of it) - you cannot just refer to an arbitrary location, as far as I know. If you must have this (config somewhere arbitrary), then I believe you have to roll your own and load the relevant config bits from that  location in code, and handle WCF configuration in code, too

Comment: @Xefan The answer is correct. To apply the solution, you can change the client tag to: `<client configSource="Client.config" />` Also in your solution for your `Client.config` file, set `Copy To Output Directory` to `true`.

Comment: The problem isn't merely separating out the file, that's trivial as you state. The problem is separating it out to somewhere that a standard user account will have permission to write. Creating another config in program files leaves me with the exact same problem in that only an administrator will be able to modify the config there, hence why this configuration needs to go to somewhere where a standard user in a typical secure windows system will have permission to write, such as the user's %appdata% folder.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for as well.  I want to locate an external config file in the %appdata% folder so that it can be edited by the end user as necessary.  Why is this so difficult to accomplish?